# FullCalendar plugins not recognised via CDN

Tags: reactjs, plugins, fullcalendar, cdn, codepen

I'm trying to run a simple component on CodePen. In `settings` -> `JS` there is a section to add external scripts via a CDN. I've added the following:

```
https://unpkg.com/react/umd/react.development.js
https://unpkg.com/react-dom/umd/react-dom.development.js
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fullcalendar/react@5.9.0/dist/main.cjs.min.js
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fullcalendar/daygrid@5.9.0/main.global.min.js
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fullcalendar/list@5.9.0/main.global.min.js
```

There are no issues with the first three - I can use react state and components, and the `<FullCalendar />` component is recognised. However, the `daygrid` or `list` plugins do not work. The following error appears in the console: `ReferenceError: dayGridPlugin is not defined`

Any ideas on why CodePen is not recognising this from the import? Or how this is supposed to be implemented? View it [here](https://codepen.io/isoaxe/pen/qBmzdqY)

```
const { useState } = React;

function Calendar (props) {
  const [modalOpen, setModalOpen] = useState(false);

  function addEvent () {
    setModalOpen(true);
  }
  
  return (
    <FullCalendar
      plugins={[ dayGridPlugin, listPlugin ]}
      headerToolbar={{
        start: "prev,next today addEvent",
        center: "title",
        end: "dayGridMonth listWeek",
      }}
      customButtons={{
        addEvent: {
          text: "+",
          click: addEvent,
        }
      }}
      initialView="dayGridMonth"
    />
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Calendar />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: dayGridPlugin won't be defined as variable because you haven't defined it. You'd need to be using a build system and then import it as per https://fullcalendar.io/docs/react or https://fullcalendar.io/docs/initialize-es6. as far as I know, CodePen doesn't really support that (but I could be wrong, I haven't tried, maybe they have some documentation you could look up). You might need to use a different site like codesandbox. In fact https://fullcalendar.io/docs/react has a link to a runnable codesandbox project you can use and fork to get started.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think it should be possible on CodePen though. There are [create-react-app](https://codepen.io/MrMaster/pen/oNYWNjr) projects for instance. There is even old implementations of FullCalendar in React. This [example](https://codepen.io/DaikiNakamura/pen/MpgMpo?editors=1010) is from v.2 and uses jQuery too, but uses views without plugins (maybe the FullCalendar api has changed since). I'll try modifying the CRA project since the build system is already set up there.

Comment: What I don't get is why `React`, `ReactDOM` and the `FullCalendar` component could be imported without issue via the CDN, but the plugins cannot. Those 3 did not need to be defined before use - the importing script covered that. Why should it be different for the plugins?

Comment: Maybe this should be a seperate question, but no top-level `import` statement for `FullCalendar` works at all (the working module above was via an external `<script>`). There are no errors in the console, the screen just goes blank. By comparison, there are no issues importing and implementing `react`, react-dom` or even `react-modal`.

Comment: `maybe the FullCalendar api has changed since`...yes, significantly. But it's largely irrelevant - the main difference is it isn't using imports or ES6 build techniques. You can also make fullcalendar 5 work without ES6 syntax (see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/initialize-globals), but I'm not sure about React (as I'm not a user of it). Likewise I'm not sure what the important difference is between the create-react-app template you shared and your codepen. have you tried copying that template as a starting point?

Comment: It occurs to me that perhaps you're supposed to install the plugins as npm packages rather than just linking to the CDN - there's an option for that in the CodePen. Other than that, I'm out of ideas. Perhaps someone with React experience will see this post, or perhaps you could raise a ticket on fullcalendar's github about it, in case the makers of the react plugin have any advice. Sorry I can't help further.

Comment: I've tried forking the CRA template, but `FullCalendar` still isn't recognised. No issues with other react packages as [I've demonstrated](https://codepen.io/isoaxe/pen/yLbmBeY). Installing plugins as NPM packages was the first thing I tried. That's what I was referring to in my last comment - the screen goes white with no errors. I'll raise it as an issue as you suggest, though it's likely an error on my side. Thanks for your help!